# change internal class style to overflow: visible for specific class (For PrimeNG)

Tags: css, angular, primeng

**This question is specific to PrimeNG or angular2 components. Their styles are hidden but on documentation page they mention, although quite vaguely.
Here is url: http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog**

How could one change styles of a component?

For example for Dialog component we have style and styleClass:

```
style       string  null    Inline style of the component.
styleClass  string  null    Style class of the component.
```

Also we have a class `ui-dialog-content Content element`.

Now I want to change for ui-dialog-content overflow style to visible. What should I do?

This is quite unclear from documentation.

I have tried create a class

```
.dialog-overflow{
  overflow: visible;
}
```

and set `<p-dialog styleClass="dialog-overflow" ...` but that obviously does not work as it is not correct class (ui-dialog-content).

**Update:**
I have tried with no success this option also:

```
.dialog-overflow .ui-dialog-content {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

and this:

```
.dialog-overflow >>> .ui-dialog-content {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this was solution.

```
p-dialog >>> .ui-dialog-content {
  overflow: visible;
}    

p-dialog >>> .ui-dialog{
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Double overflow for this component to go through two nested divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class you already have:

```
.ui-dialog-content {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

---

But I believe you are making a mistake here. The class is not set using `styleClass="abc"` but using `class="abc"`. But I'm not overly proficient in angular, so I'm basing my knowledge on HTML.

So you should do the following:

```
<p-dialog class="dialog-overflow"></p-dialog>
```

And use the CSS you provided before:

```
.dialog-overflow{
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I was not quite specific with this question. It is not general css question. Now I have added a little bit more to the top. ui-dialog-content is not my class but a part of component that I am using and somehow hidden from me...